# Looker custom visualization API - Visualization config options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, looker

I'm currently utilizing the looker API to create custom visualization. I'm using https://github.com/looker-open-source/custom_visualizations_v2/blob/master/docs/api_reference.md as a reference for the visualization API.
I suppose the documentation does not include all UI setup properties (this issue is example of that: https://github.com/looker/custom_visualizations_v2/issues/130):
https://github.com/looker-open-source/custom_visualizations_v2/blob/master/docs/api_reference.md#Where can I find complete documentation for all available looker option property names, such as type, display, default, label, etc.?

Also, is it possible to override looker option default behavior. for example: for type - "string" default behavior is to display label on top of the input like this: [Default behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76LAX.png). I would like to get this type of apperance: [What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O9qp.png). Because my custom visualization is rendered inside iframe and creates shadow dom, I can't override UI for looker options from my application.

Finally, I would like to know if it is possible to use react component as value for visualization config property.

As I previously indicated, I attempted to find information in the Looker documentation, in github repositories that provided examples of custom visualization projects, and by posting a question on the Google Cloud Forum, but I received no response. To clarify my final query, anything along the lines of this ought to work:

```
properties: {
  myCustomElement: {
    type: "custom",
    label: "Custom Element",
    render: true,
    default: <CustomComponent />, // <-- react component
  },
},
```

It doesn't, though, because looker won't render the values "custom" or "component" because it doesn't recognize them. Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'MessagePort': Symbol (react.element) could not be cloned is another problem that is produced by this code snippet. I am familiar with Json and I know that this error is fixed by JSON.Stringify, although in my case in the end I still don't get working looker option.
Thank you for your responses in advance.